# how can i pass data by using react navigation in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have a NotifiCard component and a ReplyComment component

When I run the LookforReply function, the GETONECOMMENT_REQUEST and LOAD_POST_REQUEST dispatches are executed, and the data comes into onecomment.

which is

```
    const {onecomment} = useSelector((state) => state.post);
```

And I also want to pass the {item:one comment} data in the ReplyComment using navigation.navigate.

However, when we run our code, the data does not come into ReplyComment immediately, so it causing an error.

this is my code

(NotifiCard.js)

```
    const NotifiCard = ({item}) => {

        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const navigation = useNavigation();
      const {onecomment} = useSelector((state) => state.post);
      

        const LookforReply = useCallback(() => {
            dispatch({
                type:GETONECOMMENT_REQUEST,
                data:item?.CommentId,
            }),
            dispatch({
                type: LOAD_POST_REQUEST,
                data:item.PostId,
              }),
            navigation.navigate('ReplyComment',{itemm:onecomment})
              },[]);


        return (
        <LookContainer onPress={LookforReply}>
            <Label>대댓보기</Label>
            </LookContainer>
        );
    };
```

when dispatch GETONECOMMENT_REQUEST, getonecommentAPI this api run and get data from backend router

(postsaga.js)

```
    function getonecommentAPI(data) {
      return axios.get(`/post/${data}/getonecomment`);
    }

    function* getonecomment(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(getonecommentAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: GETONECOMMENT_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        yield put({
          type: GETONECOMMENT_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }

 which is this backend router
```

(backend/post.js)

```
    router.get('/:onecommentId/getonecomment', async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
            //  console.log("req.params.onecomment:",req.params.onecommentId);      
    
            const onecomment = await Comment.findOne({
              where:{id: req.params.onecommentId},
              include: [{
                model: User,
                attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
              }],
            })

            //  console.log("onecomment:",JSON.stringify(onecomment));
        res.status(200).json(onecomment);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        next(error);
      }
    });
```

if i get result data this will put  draft.onecomment

(reducer/post.js)

```
      case GETONECOMMENT_REQUEST:
        draft.loadPostLoading = true;
        draft.loadPostDone = false;
        draft.loadPostError = null;
        break;
      case GETONECOMMENT_SUCCESS:
        // console.log("action.data:::",action.data);
        draft.loadPostLoading = false;
        draft.onecomment = action.data;
        draft.loadPostDone = true;
        break;
      case GETONECOMMENT_FAILURE:
        draft.loadPostLoading = false;
        draft.loadPostError = action.error;
        break;
```

and i can get data in onecomment by using useselector at (NotifiCard.js)

```
  const {onecomment} = useSelector((state) => state.post);
```

what i want is that when i press LookforReply i want to pass itemm data to
ReplyComment component but if i press LookforReply, i can't get itemm data
Immediately

(ReplyComment.js)

```
   const ReplyComment = ({route}) => {

      const {itemm} = route.params;
     console.log("itemm",itemm);
      return (
        <Container>
          <TodoListView parenteitem={itemm} />
          <AddTodo item={itemm} />
         
        </Container>
    
      );
    };
```

I think that the LookforReply function is executed asynchronously and navigate is executed before the onecomment data comes in, and it doesn't seem to be able to deliver the itemm.

so how can i fix my code?....

Comment: I guess you are making the API call to fetch replies to the comment in the reducer?

Comment: This can work, but really should be avoided. See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#rules-of-reducers

Comment: Need your help to understand when `onecomment` is fetched

Comment: @cltsang i don't use fetch i call api by using axios..

Comment: Idea is the same. API calls shouldn't happen in reducer. Maybe let me paraphrase: the answer depends on when `onecomment` is returned. Please show the API call and how they connect.

Comment: @cltsang i updated my post can you check this?